# Updating a UILabel from an escaping closure doesn't take effect immedialtely

Tags: ios, swift

**Basically**:

In viewDidAppear:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    myFunction(closure)
}
```

`closure`is of type `@escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void`

In the closure code:

```
print("Change myLabel.text")
self?.myLabel.text = "New Title"
print("myLabel.text changed")
```

`"Show myLabel.text"` and `"myLabel.text changed"` are printed as soon as the VC appears, but the text in `myLabel` changes after several seconds (around 10 seconds).

`myLabel` is created programmatically as seen below:

```
class MyClass : UIViewController {
    ...
    var myLabel: UILabel!
    var contacts = [ContactEntry]()
    ...
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        myLabel = UILabel()
        myLabel.text = "Original title"
        myLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 400)
        self.view.addSubview(myLabel)
    } 
}
```

The actual code is inspired from [here](https://github.com/DigitalLeaves/AddressBookContacts):

**viewDidAppear**:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    requestAccessToContacts { [weak self] (success) in
        if success {
            self?.retrieveContacts(completion: { (success, contacts) in
                self?.tableView.isHidden = false
                self?.myLabel.isHidden = true
                if success && (contacts?.count)! > 0 {
                    self?.contacts = contacts!
                    self?.myLabel.text = ""
                    self?.myLabel.isHidden = true
                    self?.tableView.reloadData()
                } else if (contacts?.count)! == 0 {
                    self?.myLabel.isHidden = false
                    self?.myLabel.text = "No contacts found"
                } else {{
                    self?.myLabel.isHidden = false
                    self?.myLabel.text = "Error loading contacts"
                }
            })
        } else {
            print("Change label text")
            self?.myLabel.attributedText = "Enable access to contacts by going to\nSettings>Privacy>Contacts>MyApp"
            self?.myLabel.isHidden = false
            print("Label text changed")
        }
    }
}
```

**requestAccessToContacts**:

```
func requestAccessToContacts(completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {

    let authorizationStatus = CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: CNEntityType.contacts)

    switch authorizationStatus {
    case .authorized:
        // authorized previously
        completion(true)

    case .denied, .notDetermined:
        // needs to ask for authorization
        self.contactStore.requestAccess(for: CNEntityType.contacts, completionHandler: { (accessGranted, error) -> Void in
            completion(accessGranted)
        })

    default:
        // not authorized.
        completion(false)
    }
}
```

**retrieveContacts**:

```
func retrieveContacts(completion: (_ success: Bool, _ contacts: [ContactEntry]?) -> Void) {
    var contacts = [ContactEntry]()
    do {
        let contactsFetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactImageDataAvailableKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey].map {$0 as CNKeyDescriptor})
        try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: contactsFetchRequest, usingBlock: { (cnContact, error) in
            if let contact = ContactEntry(cnContact: cnContact) { contacts.append(contact) }
        })
        completion(true, contacts)
    } catch {
        completion(false, nil)
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You should not add subviews in viewWillLayoutSubviews method. Try to initialize myLabel somewhere in viewDidLoad and just update it's frame in viewWillLayoutSubviews.

Comment: "so he'll be adding a zillion labels". That's exactly why I said it's a wrong place. Creating more and more labels is obviously not what is expected here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying:

```
print("Change myLabel.text")
self?.myLabel.text = "New Title"
print("myLabel.text changed")
```

And you are complaining that the print messages appear in the console but the label doesn't change until much later.

This sort of delay is nearly always caused by a threading issue. You do not show MyFunction and you do not show the entirety of `closure`, so it's impossible to help you in detail, but the likelihood is that you are messing around with background threads without knowing what you are doing, and that you have accidentally set `myLabel.text` on a background thread, which is a big no-no. You must step out to the *main thread* in order to touch the interface in any way:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print("Change myLabel.text")
    self?.myLabel.text = "New Title"
    print("myLabel.text changed")
    // ... and everything else that touches the interface
}
```

Comment: I know you're right, my question is _how_ to update the UI from that thread (i.e from an escaping closure)

Comment: Basically that's it